# align columns of letters?

Tags: python, alignment

this is only a part of my code but I was having trouble with aligning it
I want it to print out an output in the following fashion:

```
N a m e
1 2 3 4
```

right now it does something like this:

```
['J', 'o', 'h', 'n', ' ', 'S', 'm', 'i', 't', 'h']
['[', '1', ',', ' ', '6', ',', ' ', '8', ',', ' ', '5', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '4', ',', ' ', '9', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '8', ']']
```

just a heads up I'm still new to python haha

```
print("Your name and numeric value is:")
fullname = first_name + " " + last_name
print(list(fullname))

name = first_name + last_name
name = str.lower(name)
output = []
for letter in name:
    number = (ord(letter) - 97)%9 + 1
    output.append(number)
print(list(str(output)))
```

Comment: so whats the problem ?

Comment: @Kasra I want to align each letter into columns so the first and second line are uniform

Comment: can you add a more clearly input and desire out put ?

Comment: Can you show us what is being printed now?

Comment: i edited it to show an ex. output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
first_name = 'Foo'
last_name = 'Bar'

print("Your name and numeric value is:")
fullname = first_name + ' ' + last_name
print(' '.join(fullname))

fullname = str.lower(fullname)
output = ''
for letter in fullname:
    if letter == ' ':
        output += '  '
    else:
        number = (ord(letter) - 97)%9 + 1
        output += str(number) + ' '
print(output)
```

Output:

```
F o o   B a r
6 6 6   2 1 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
print(list(fullname))
```

Use:

```
print(''.join('%3s' % c for c in fullname))
```

And instead of:

```
print(list(str(output)))
```

Use:

```
print(''.join('%3s' % n for n in output))
```

With that you'll get everything with 2 spaces and right justified, even when the numbers have more than a single digit.

Answer (score 0):

Use the .join string method:

> name = first_name + last_name
>
> name = str.lower(name)
>
> output = ' '.join(name)

The ' ' before the method marks what will join the parts. In this case, blank spaces.

if name where to be `['j','h','o','n']` this would return `j h o n`